# Is it possible to capture data from a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a scenario where I'm calculating something in the `WHERE` clause of my SQL, but I also want to get that calculation - since it's expensive. Is it possible to get the results of something done in the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
SELECT `foo` FROM `table` WHERE (foo = LongCalculation(`column`))
```

Wishful thinking, or possible with MySQL?

**EDIT:** Calculation is column dependent

Comment: If you've got 1000 rows and LongCalculation is going to run with 1000 different inputs then there is no solution. But if the amount of different values are much less than 1000 then you could maybe use intermediate cache storage inside the LongCalculation which would of course have to be a stored procedure. Don't know if it's possible to retain variable values between stored procedure calls though.

Comment: You could probably use a temporary table for storing calculated outputs for specific inputs.

Comment: See my answer for how I solved this. I wasn't trying to avoid calculating each row, just more than once for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of re-working @cherouvim's idea and I got it to work with row-dependent functions:

```
set @bar = 0;

SELECT
  `product_name`,
  @bar AS `stock`
FROM `jos_vm_product`
WHERE (@bar := `product_in_stock`) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set @bar = LongCalculation();
select foo from table where foo=@bar;
```

Comment: +1: assuming `LongCalculation` is not row-dependent (does not take any columns from the `table`.